# React Native: Issue with ScrollView - Content Not Scrolling Properly

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently facing a challenge in my React Native project related to the ScrollView component. Despite having content that exceeds the screen height, the scroll functionality is not working as expected. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView>
        <Text>Content 1</Text>
        <Text>Content 2</Text>
        {/* ... more content */}
        <Text>Content N</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Even though the content extends beyond the screen height, the app doesn't enable scrolling. I've tried using flex: 1 and adjusting styles, but the issue persists.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem with the ScrollView not allowing proper scrolling of content? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at this, if you have a style of flex:1 for both your view and your scroll view, it should work, else, Can you share you complete code and is your component being used as a child widget in another component?